# LaTeX - Como transformar uma table em longtable?

Tags: table, latex

Tenho uma tabela que ficou muito grade.

Gostaria de transforma-la em uma long table. Como faço ?

Já tentei exluir o \begin{table} e alterar o \begin{tabular} para \begin{longtable}, mas não deu certo. A tabela fica descentralizada e some na quebra da página.

```
\begin{table}[H]
   \IBGEtab{
       \caption{ Contras e empresas que destoam de Benford ao menos nos três últimos anos para o primeiro dígito}
        \label{tablivreadm1d}
        }{%
        \begin{tabular}{p{2.4cm}|p{2cm}|p{9cm}}
        \hline
        \textbf{CONTA}  & \textbf{CNPJ} & \textbf{NOME}\\
        \hline
        \multirow{59}[1]{*}{Receita} & 694389 \newline\newline 
698609  \newline\newline 
1151186 \newline\newline 
1152097 \newline\newline 
1566038 \newline\newline 
1667766 \newline\newline 
2057584 \newline\newline 
2309070 \newline\newline 
2335109 \newline\newline 
2923389 \newline\newline 
3222753 \newline\newline 
3645752 \newline\newline 
3732359 \newline\newline 
4876393 \newline\newline 
19869338 \newline\newline 
23949522 \newline\newline 
24048910 \newline\newline 
26408161 \newline\newline 
37255049 \newline\newline 
37442605 \newline\newline 
38588174 \newline\newline 
41669227 \newline\newline 
41707258 \newline\newline 
41931445 \newline\newline 
64237530 \newline\newline 
65229254 \newline\newline 
66398496 \newline\newline 
66402207    & 
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\newline\newline XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\newline\newline XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\newline\newline
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX \newline\newline
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX \newline\newline
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX \newline\newline XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\newline\newline 
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX \newline\newline 
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX \newline\newline 
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX \newline\newline 
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX \newline\newline 
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX \newline\newline XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\newline\newline 
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX \newline\newline 
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX  \newline\newline XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\newline\newline XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\newline\newline 
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX \newline\newline 
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\newline\newline 
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX \newline\newline 
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX \newline\newline
 XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX \newline\newline XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\newline\newline
 XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX \newline\newline 
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX \newline\newline 
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX \newline\newline
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX \\

        \hline

        \multirow{59}[1]{*}{Despesa} &  68987 \newline\newline
694389  \newline\newline 
968602 \newline\newline 
1009908 \newline\newline 
1259518 \newline\newline 
1566038 \newline\newline 
1664968 \newline\newline 
2144899 \newline\newline 
2338666 \newline\newline 
3047549 \newline\newline 
3222753 \newline\newline 
3645752 \newline\newline 
4484490 \newline\newline 
7026923 \newline\newline 
8742188 \newline\newline 
11907520 \newline\newline 
21661202 \newline\newline 
21682737 \newline\newline 
23949522 \newline\newline 
25404542 \newline\newline 
25420696 \newline\newline 
26960328 \newline\newline 
32430233 \newline\newline 
33579731 \newline\newline 
37395399 \newline\newline 
41255225 \newline\newline 
41753500  \newline\newline 
41805003 \newline\newline 
41931445 \newline\newline 
66262643 & 
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX \newline\newline
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX \newline\newline
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX \newline\newline 
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX \newline\newline
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX \newline\newline
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX \newline\newline
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX \newline\newline
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX \newline\newline
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX \newline\newline 
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX \newline\newline 
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX \newline\newline 
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX \newline\newline 
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX \newline\newline 
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX \newline\newline 
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX \newline\newline
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX \newline\newline 
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX \newline\newline 
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX \newline\newline 
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXx \newline\newline
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX \newline\newline 
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX \newline\newline 
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX \newline\newline 
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX \newline\newline 
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX \newline\newline 
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX \newline\newline 
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX \newline\newline 
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX \newline\newline 
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX \newline\newline 
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX \newline\newline 
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX \newline\newline 
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX \\

        \hline

        \multirow{9}[1]{*}{Caixa} & 
3222753\newline\newline 
4463602 \newline\newline 
21866694 \newline\newline 
22656789 \newline\newline 
26408187 \newline\newline 
41683228  & 
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX \newline\newline 
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX \newline\newline 
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX \newline\newline 
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX \newline\newline  
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX \newline\newline 
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX \\ 

      \hline

      \multirow{1}[1]{*}{PCLD} & - &  - \\
      \hline
      \end{tabular}
   }{
      \legend{Fonte: Elaborado pelo autor.}
     }
\end{table}
```

Desde já, obrigado.

Comment: Este erro não é reproduzível. Particularmente, não sei o que a macro `\IBGEtab` faz. Assim, não tenho como reproduzir este problema em meu computador e verificar o porquê dele não funcionar.